# Incompatible types: 'PAnsiChar' and 'PWideChar'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I am very new in delphi XE8.  I have this following code which is from my delphi version 6 and I want to run it in delphi XE8.

```
1. function UTF8ToStringLen(const src: PChar; const Len: Cardinal): widestring;
2. var
3.   l: Integer;
4. begin
5.   SetLength(Result, Len);
6.   if Len > 0 then
7.   begin                                             
8.     l := MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, src, Len, PWChar(Result), Len*SizeOf(WideChar));  <--error
9.     SetLength(Result, l);
10.   end;
11. end;
12. 
13. 
14. function StringToUTF8Len(const src: PChar; const Len: Cardinal): string;
15. var
16.   bsiz: Integer;
17.   Temp: string;
18. begin
19.   bsiz := Len * 3;
20.   SetLength(Temp, bsiz);
21.   if bsiz > 0 then
22.   begin
23.     StringToWideChar(src, PWideChar(Temp), bsiz);
24.     SetLength(Result, bsiz);                
25.     bsiz := WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, PWideChar(Temp), -1, PChar(Result), bsiz, nil, nil);  <--error
26.     if bsiz > 0 then dec(bsiz);
27.     SetLength(Result, bsiz);
28.   end;
29. end;
```

when I try to run it the error points to line 8 and 25 in the code with an error message saying

```
ERROR MESSAGE: Incompatible types: 'PAnsiChar' and 'PWideChar'
```

I have search everywhere for the solution but I just cant solve the problem. Please help.. Thank you.

Comment: As XE8 is Unicode enabled PChar is similar to PWideChar. To solve your problem declare src: PAnsiChar. You might have more to do, though. I suggest reading the whitepaper about Unicode from Marco Cantú: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Delphi 2007 and earlier, `PChar` is an alias for `PAnsiChar`. In Delphi 2009 and later, `PChar` is an alias for `PWideChar`. So by changing compiler you change the meaning of the code.

You can resolve this simply by replacing `PChar` with `PAnsiChar` and the code will have its original meaning.

In modern Unicode Delphi it would be more natural to use `string` (alias of `UnicodeString`) instead of the COM `WideString`. You might also use of one the many library routines to perform UTF-8 conversion.

There are surely going to be other issues ahead of you. I recommend that you read [Marco Cantù's whitepaper on Unicode in Delphi](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980) as your next move.

Comment: And another déjà vu.

Answer (score 3):

From the MDSN:

- [MultiByteToWideChar function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx)

  ```
  int MultiByteToWideChar(
   _In_      UINT   CodePage,
   _In_      DWORD  dwFlags,
   _In_      LPCSTR lpMultiByteStr,
   _In_      int    cbMultiByte,
   _Out_opt_ LPWSTR lpWideCharStr,
   _In_      int    cchWideChar
  );
  ```
- [WideCharToMultiByte function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx)

  ```
  int WideCharToMultiByte(
   _In_      UINT    CodePage,
   _In_      DWORD   dwFlags,
   _In_      LPCWSTR lpWideCharStr,
   _In_      int     cchWideChar,
   _Out_opt_ LPSTR   lpMultiByteStr,
   _In_      int     cbMultiByte,
   _In_opt_  LPCSTR  lpDefaultChar,
   _Out_opt_ LPBOOL  lpUsedDefaultChar
  );
  ```
- From [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx):

  > *LPCSTR* 
  >   A pointer to a constant null-terminated string of 8-bit Windows (**ANSI**) characters.
  >   This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
  >   `typedef __nullterminated CONST CHAR *LPCSTR;`
  >   
  >   *LPSTR*
  >   A pointer to a null-terminated string of 8-bit Windows (**ANSI**) characters.
  >   This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
  >   `typedef CHAR *LPSTR;`

---

The issue related to your code is that the argument `lpMultiByteStr` of each function is a `PAnsiChar` and you're passing a `PChar` as a parameter.
The `PChar` is an alias of `PAnsiChar` in *Delphi 6* and stands for a `PWideChar` in *Delphi XE8*.

- You can solve this issue at line #8 declaring you function (and calling it accordingly) like this:
  `function UTF8ToStringLen(const src: PAnsiChar; const Len: Cardinal): WideString;`
- To solve the issue at line #25, change the function declaration like:
  `function StringToUTF8Len(const src: PAnsiChar; const Len: Cardinal): string;`
   and the "*infamous*" line:
  `bsiz := WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, PWideChar(Temp), -1, PAnsiChar(Result), bsiz, nil, nil);`

In each case [David Heffernan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266057/incompatible-types-pansichar-and-pwidechar/32266263#32266263) applies.